# C# RazorLight not working when build in release

Tags: c#, razorengine, razorlight

I installed in my project **RazorLight**. It work fine locally, but when I build it in release mode this is the error:

```
Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery
```

I already did what documentation says, so I changed my `*.csproj` in this way:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
    <PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`PreserveCompilationReferences` and `PreserveCompilationContext` don't seem to work. .Net 7.0 could be the problem?

In program I also have this line of code:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Where could be the issue?

Comment: Some people resolved by adding a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` nuget package.

Comment: @Alberto unfortunatly I already have this reference and doesn't solve the problem